# How to change body size of slave pages in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, master-pages

I am designing a web application using **ASP.NET**, and I have a template for my website. 
In order to prevent code duplication, I used a **Master page** and designed my website template in there. Then I added as many forms as was needed and referenced to the Master page.
In next step, in order to add content to the forms, I used a `ContentPlaceHolder`.

Size of the body or form in Master page is not variable. moreover, I have variable amount of content in each form. As a result, the height of my form may be different from each other.

My question is then what should I do to have forms with variable height (not width and only height) at the same time using the Master page? Is there other solutions instead of using Master page to to such a work (except using the code for each form separately, because it is not a good way)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - have you set the height on the Masterpage? It is generally considered best practice **not** to set height in HTML, it will automatically adjust based on the content in normal block context. Set the width, and let the browser determine the height based on the content. Can you be more specific with your question if this isn't your problem.

Comment: as I told, it is rather simple!  Thanks, it seems that the problem is solved!